# Display chosen text on JavaScript button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching to the internet, but could not find the right answer on this question. How could I fix a JavaScript button that display the chosen text. For example when I click on Germany. The text of this button will be changed to Language: Germany. Check photo and codes below to better understand this issue.

[image]

```js
$(function() {
$("button").click(function(){
 $(".choose").toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<button type="button"><img src="Img/global logo.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""> Language:</button>
<div class="choose">
<br>
<p>
This changes the language of the site.</p>
<hr>
<div class="language">
<ul class="country">
<li data-type="Brazil"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/BR.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Brazil</li>
<li data-type="China"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/CN.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> China</li>
<li data-type="France"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/FR.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> France</li>
<li data-type="Germany"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/DE.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Germany</li>
<li data-type="Hong Kong"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/HK.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Hong Kong</li>
<li data-type="India"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/IN.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> India</li>
<li data-type="Indonesia"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/ID.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Indonesia</li>
<li data-type="Malaysia"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/MY.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Malaysia</li>
<li data-type="Netherlands"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/NL.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""> Netherlands</li>
<li data-type="Philippines"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/PH.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Philippines</li>
<li data-type="Singapore"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/SG.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Singapore</li>
<li data-type="Taiwan"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/TW.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Taiwan</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what specific part is causing you problems or is hard to find? Seems like a very standard dropdown menu that just needs to update html when selection made

Comment: That photo is not a dropdown-menu, but a language button that I have copied from YouTube website. If you click on that button, the entire span will fade out. Subsequently you can choose a language for instance Germany and the text of that button (language:English) will change to  Language: Germany.

Comment: Ok...how that *"menu"* gets displayed isn't really that critical ... the principles are the same. One click handler for the button, one for the selection. Still not clear what the problems are

Comment: Maybe it was my bad. If have changed the text button to Language:. Hopefully you now understand this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a container into which to write the chosen language, so wrap a `<span>` around the word Language, and give it an ID so it is easy to select.

Then, some code like this should do the trick:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eg2z88ru/)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Updated jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eg2z88ru/2/)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Updated jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eg2z88ru/3/)</kbd>

```
$('ul li').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); //prevent firing twice (once for li, once for ul)
        var t = $(this).data('type');
        $('#lang').text( t );
        $('.language').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank for the effort you have taken to help me. I have made a mistake with  the Button text, this should be "Language:" instead of "Global Home".

Comment: Just put a <span> (with a unique ID name) around that text, and use the same code. [Updated example here](https://jsfiddle.net/eg2z88ru/2/) - I also removed the `.hide()` instruction because it's not necessary

Comment: I would like to fade out the div class=language when clicking <button>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chiholiu/wewyydnd/5/#&togetherjs=vhMG8r4bem I have this thus far and want to toggle entire language list when clicking on the <button>. After choosing the language, the language name should be displayed on <button>.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally find the answer partly due gibberish who helped me solving this issue. After a long try the final answer is:

```js
$(function() {
$('button, li').click(function(){
 var t = $(this).data('type');
    $('#lang').text( t );
    $('.language').toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<button type="button"><img src="Img/global logo.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""> Country:<span id="lang"> England</span></button>
<div class="choose">
<br>
<p>This changes the language of the site.</p>
<hr>
<div class="language">
<ul class="country">
<li data-type="Brazil"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/BR.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Brazil</li>
<li data-type="China"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/CN.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> China</li>
<li data-type="England"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/GB.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> England</li>
<li data-type="Germany"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/DE.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Germany</li>
<li data-type="Hong Kong"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/HK.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Hong Kong</li>
<li data-type="India"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/IN.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> India</li>
<li data-type="Indonesia"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/ID.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Indonesia</li>
<li data-type="Malaysia"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/MY.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Malaysia</li>
<li data-type="Netherlands"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/NL.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""> Netherlands</li>
<li data-type="Philippines"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/PH.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Philippines</li>
<li data-type="Singapore"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/SG.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Singapore</li>
<li data-type="Taiwan"><img src="Img/Flags-Icon-Set/24x24/TW.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""/> Taiwan</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```